# Mapping with generic destination doesn't work?

Tags: c#, generics, automapper

I'm trying to build out a hierarchy of mapping profiles to simplify creating mappings for new objects that fit in this hierarchy. But I'm having trouble getting  some mappings to work. A mapping I added using a generic type parameter doesn't seem to work when it's the destination type, however it works when it's a source type.

Consider the following types:

```
public interface IRequest
{
    string Input { get; }
}
public interface IResponse
{
    string Output { get; }
}
public class SomeObject
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
abstract class BaseProfile<TSource, TDestination> : Profile
    where TSource : IRequest
    where TDestination : IResponse
{
    protected BaseProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<TSource, SomeObject>()
            .ForMember(src => src.Value, opt => opt.MapFrom(dest => dest.Input));
        CreateMap<SomeObject, TDestination>()
            .ForMember(src => src.Output, opt => opt.MapFrom(dest => dest.Value));
    }
}
```

I want to be able to make it so the profile for concrete types can use the mappings in this parent profile so I'd be able to define this:

```
class FooRequest : IRequest
{
    public string Input { get; set; }
}
class FooResponse : IResponse
{
    public string Output { get; set; }
}
class FooProfile : BaseProfile<FooRequest, FooResponse>
{
    public FooProfile()
    {
    }
}
```

However, the mapping to the response object doesn't map at all.

```
Mapper.Initialize(c => c.AddProfiles(typeof(FooProfile).Assembly));
var request = new FooRequest { Input = "FOO" };
var obj = Mapper.Map<SomeObject>(request); // this works
// obj.Value = "FOO"
var response = Mapper.Map<FooResponse>(obj); // this doesn't
// response.Output = null
```

It seems to fix this, I have to duplicate the mapping I thought I had already created but using the concrete type.

```
public FooProfile()
{
    // Adding this works
    CreateMap<SomeObject, FooResponse>()
        .ForMember(src => src.Output, opt => opt.MapFrom(dest => dest.Value));
}
```

Is there something I'm missing to make this work? Or will I have to create those explicit mappings every time?

---

As pointed out in Scott's answer, the problem ultimately is that the interface the generic parameter is constrained by does not have settable properties. But Nader  also found that using a particular overload of the `ForMember()` method works. So rather than binding to the member directly, we bind to the member name instead. This works fine for my needs.

```
protected BaseProfile()
{
    CreateMap<TSource, SomeObject>()
        .ForMember(src => src.Value, opt => opt.MapFrom(dest => dest.Input));
    CreateMap<SomeObject, TDestination>()
        .ForMember(nameof(IResponse.Output), opt => opt.MapFrom(dest => dest.Value));
}
```

Comment: its work with that overload!!! maybe jimmy using the the result in more than one ways `CreateMap(typeof(SomeObject), typeof(TDestination))
     .ForMember("Output", opt => opt.MapFrom("Value"));`

Comment: Hmm, you're right, though the only thing that would have to change is the first parameter to the `ForMember()` call. So rather than binding to the `IResponse.Output` member, we're binding to the `Output` name. Put it up as an answer, that will be a fine solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried many ways but with no chance, but this overload just worked with private contract setters

```
abstract class BaseProfile<TSource, TDestination> : Profile
        where TSource : IRequest
        where TDestination : IResponse
    {
        protected BaseProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<TSource, SomeObject>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Value, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Input));
            CreateMap(typeof(SomeObject), typeof(TDestination))
                .ForMember("Output", opt => opt.MapFrom("Value"));
        }
    }
```

Maybe jimmy using the the result in more than one ways

Answer (score 3):

Add a setter to the `Output` property of `IResponse`.

```
public interface IResponse
{
    string Output { get; set; }
}
```

It's trying to map to an `IReponse` and it can't set the property because it's not writable.

Perhaps that's not what you want because you don't want `IResponse` to have a writable property. But that's why it's not getting set.

In that case the only workaround I can determine is to create a base response that implements `IResponse` and has a writable property.

```
class ResponseBase : IResponse
{
    public string Output { get; set; }
}

class FooResponse : ResponseBase
{
}
```

Then change your generic constraint to the base class instead of the interface:

```
abstract class BaseProfile<TSource, TDestination> : Profile
    where TSource : IRequest
    where TDestination : ResponseBase
```

That generic constraint will determine how the target type is cast, and in turn whether the property is seen as writable.

Comment: Oh, that simple. Right on, thanks! I definitely would prefer to leave the properties as readonly so hopefully there's a different option.